# How to ignore fractional seconds with MySQL 5.6?

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.6.4 and up supports fractional seconds for temporal column type.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

But I want to ignore fractional seconds part for compatibility.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `t1` (`created` datetime(0) NOT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.41 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 set created = '2013-08-27 05:13:21.999';
mysql> INSERT INTO t1 set created = '2013-08-27 23:59:59.999';


mysql> select * from t1;
+---------------------+
| created             |
+---------------------+
| 2013-08-27 05:13:22 |
| 2013-08-28 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
2 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Expected result is '2013-08-27 05:13:21' and '2013-08-27 23:59:59'.

How do I save same result with previous version of MySQL?

Comment: how do you say your expected in less than 1 sec ?

Comment: Do you want it display the records only at select level ?

Comment: I want to keep compatibility of datetime calculation, updated example case in question.

Comment: I got the answer for you... just posting it..

Comment: can you try my answer now ?

Comment: As per Mysql docs `datetime(0)` means there is no fractional part, I think you found a bug.

Comment: @shoma : can you do an upvote for my answer if it helps you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to create the table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (dt DATETIME(6) NOT NULL);
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9086/1/0)**

Comment: It looks a good solution for my case. I'll try with "ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY `created` datetime(6);"

Answer (score 0):

use **SUBTIME** function for subtracting fractions from time..

Try this... subtract the microsecond from original time then convert to date format...

```
SELECT cast(SUBTIME(created,cast(concat('0:0:0.',(microsecond(created))) as time)) as datetime) from t1;
```

I tested it .. its working.. PFB snapshot..
[image]

Comment: Yeah, as if he didn't write in the title `MySQL 5.6`